# How to add markers to IR photographs

Tags: optics, thermal-radiation, measurements, measurement-problem, thermal-conductivity

I'm using an IR camera to identify thermal patterns.
The thermal images are similar to this [[LINK]](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/infrared-image-motherboard-thermal-imaging-examination-1608301771) image.
I'd like to add markers to the area being measured to determine dimensions and normalize the photos for the camera angle.

For example, it would be useful to add a length 'ruler' to the IR images. It would also be useful to mark the corners of the measurement area.

If this was a visible light photo of an item, it would be possible to just add a ruler to the photo or use ink to identify the corners.

What are ways to add this kind of information to an IR image?

Comment: One (convoluted) way would be to take a normal photo using a regular camera with a ruler in it, then measure the distance between two clear features of the image (say, two specific pins). Then you go back to the thermal images and now you know the distance between these two features should be the same as in the other photo.

Comment: Can't you glue an electrical resistance wire on the ruler in a zig zag pattern to mark the centimeters? The wire becomes hot when connected to a battery.